# fiona - install package to photoscan

Tags: python, fiona

I want to install fiona module with PhotoScan and I get a bug:

command :

```
./python.exe -m pip install fiona
```

(when I'm located in my python folder, of Photoscan)

error :

```
PS C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python> ./python.exe -m pip install fiona Collecting fiona   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/52/fe30f9f529edf52080e7f5a2ffe377aefd84d0aceeb2e96022b5a78b3faf/Fiona-1.7.13.tar.gz Collecting cligj>=0.4 (from fiona)   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/05/e8384e1f7c8689cd1b91818a24cc860077c73368fb285ba53fbd8556ec98/cligj-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl Collecting click-plugins (from fiona)   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/dd/fef84cf1678418f241ef542c0288bdf215bdd3e35f1fe03dc5223a2e80ba/click_plugins-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.7 in c:\program files\agisoft\photoscan pro\python\lib\site-packages (from fiona) Collecting munch (from fiona) Collecting click>=4.0 (from cligj>=0.4->fiona)   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/c1/8806f99713ddb993c5366c362b2f908f18269f8d792aff1abfd700775a77/click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl Building wheels for collected packages: fiona   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for fiona ... error   Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP-EB-~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hy53yycg\\fiona\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\HP-EB-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzzfrfqe4pip-wheel-
--python-tag cp35:   C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_python'
    warnings.warn(msg)   C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'metadata_version'
    warnings.warn(msg)   C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_external'
    warnings.warn(msg)   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\collection.py
-> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\crs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\drvsupport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\inspector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\rfc3339.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\tool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   copying .\fiona\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\bounds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\calc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\cat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\collect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\distrib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\env.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\insp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\load.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\ls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   copying .\fiona\fio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\fiona\fio   running build_ext   building 'fiona._transform' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for fiona   Running setup.py clean for fiona Failed to build fiona Installing collected packages: click, cligj, click-plugins, munch, fiona Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)   File "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\python\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode) PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Program Files\\Agisoft\\PhotoScan Pro\\python\\Lib\\site-packages\\click' You are using pip version
8.1.2, however version 18.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to customize the style ..

Comment: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

Comment: I'm agree but the link is dead..

Comment: working link in the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems it need Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, as the link in the error throwback isn't working, you can download it from here - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I can install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 I suppose ?

Comment: Correct! It is the latest version

Comment: OK! I suppose I have to reboot my computer to add my changes ?

Comment: When you install it, you should get a wizard to guide you through what to do, just follow the instructions and you should be OK

Comment: Well I'm installing it and I let you know if it's ok !

Comment: after installing. was it okay?